# How do I get my wp_nav_menu single category page to highlight the parent?

Tags: menus, categories

With the new wp_nav_menu system, it is possible to add a category as a menu item, so in my example I have a 'news' category, which is a submenu item of 'About'.

`About (page)

--news (category)

--history (page)

--contact us (page)`

The menu highlighting CSS picks up from current-menu-parent and current-menu-ancestor, so that when I'm in a submenu section, the top level menu item (e.g. 'About') is highlighted when I visit 'news'.

This works fine, apart from when I visit a post in the 'news' category, which matches is_single() and in_category('news').

As far as I can see in Firebug, the 'current-menu-parent' and 'current-menu-ancestor' is applied to the 'news' menu item, however it's not applied to the 'About' top level menu item.

Is there something I'm missing in setting up my menu? I've tried using a custom walker, however it seems that the initial menu ancestors are not being set up properly?

It seems my only solution (without resorting to a nasty JQuery hack) is to create a 'news' page which queries the news posts, rather than pointing to the news 'category'.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Dan

*Update with code sample 09/09/2010*

The way it is currently, viewing a single page in the News category http://www.example.com/2010/09/top-news-did-you-know/:

`<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-28"><a href="http://www.example.com/about/">About Us</a>

<ul class="sub-menu">

    <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy"><a href="http://www.example.com/category/events/">Events</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy current-post-ancestor current-menu-parent current-post-parent current-menu-parent"><a href="http://www.example.com/category/news/">News &#038; views</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type"><a href="http://www.example.com/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>

</ul></li>`

So you see that "About Us" doesn't have any CSS class to indicate it is a parent of the currently viewed page.

How I think it should work (and to be honest, if it doesn't do this, then it's a bug due to lack of implementation):

`<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-28"><a href="http://www.example.com/about/">About Us</a>

<ul class="sub-menu">

    <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy"><a href="http://www.example.com/category/events/">Events</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy current-post-ancestor current-menu-parent current-post-parent current-menu-parent"><a href="http://www.example.com/category/news/">News &#038; views</a></li>

    <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type"><a href="http://www.example.com/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>

</ul></li>`

This has the `current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor` CSS classes attached to the Top level menu item. It works this way for every other page, or even when viewing the category itself, just not a single page in a category.

Comment: Hi *@Dan Smart*: In general I'll concur with *Chris_O* that it's probably not possible. But I think it might be with a hook however I don't fully understand the question. Would you mind add code-formatted versions of your HTML to your question for both the way it is output and the way it needs to be output for the way you want? Please remove the non-relevant HTML, of course.

Comment: Mike - I've updated it with the appropriate example code, hopefully this helps clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not possible if a page menu item is a parent to a category menu item.

In your example if **About was a category** and **News was child category** then the About (category) menu item would be assigned:

- current-post-ancestor
- current-menu-parent
- current-post-parent

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming this. I looked at overriding the _wp_menu_item_classes_by_context function to add this, but I think I'll have to look to submit something on trac for this instead. So my only option is to create a page listing the category's contents, replicating the /category/news page?

Comment: Even if you do that About won't be highlighted when you are on a single post in news category.  I tried all variations and it only highlighted About if I made a category called about and set it as the parent category to news.  There are 3 or 4 tickets on trac regarding similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue. I couldn't find a php hack, so I used a javascript one:

```
function findAncestor(){
    var currentParentLi = document.getElementsByClassName("current-menu-parent");
    if(currentParentLi){
        var currentAncestorLi = currentParentLi[0].parentNode.parentNode;
        if(currentAncestorLi && currentAncestorLi.tagName=="LI"){
            currentAncestorLi.className += " current-menu-ancestor";
        }
    }
}
```

Put the above code in a .js file, then reference it in the head of your page and call the findAncestor() function on window.onload, i.e.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.onload = function() {
    findAncestor()
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: If you use another jQuery-based plugin you probably want to rewrite this as jQuery too, [since combining `jQuery.ready()` and `body.onload` might give conflicts](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Chris_O

So, I have a static front page, 2 main category + 1 subcategory under those, and another page. Driven by Wordpress 3.0.1 and Thesis 1.8, using Wordpress menu instead of Thesis menu.

For highlighting the main category I used:.current-post-ancestor a { 
background:#FFFFFF;}

( this highlight the main category when on single post )

For highlighting subcategory I used: .sub-menu .current-post-ancestor a { 
background:#F0EEC2;}

( this highlight the subcategory -under main category- when on single post of subcategory )

I would like **both** "main category" **and** "subcategory" to be highlighted.

But I cannot find the trick.

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

You may find this thread forum very informative, as I am closer to the solution.

http://diythemes.com/forums/showthread.php?39258-Category-highlighting-for-single-post-%28-wp-menu-%29.

Pierre